# How to move a c++ project from one location to other

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, visual-c++, qt5

I have a c++ project which i want to move from one location to another.

But when i try to do that all the header files which are in the c++ project are not found by the compiler.

What should i do so that compiler is able to locate the header files.

The files which are missing are all QT files.

These are my includes.

```
#include <gl\glew.h>
#include <glfw3.h>
#include "WavefrontRenderer.h"  // Not able to locate this one
#include "TreeModel.h"
#include "ui_WavefrontRenderer.h"  // Not able to locate this one
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>   // Not able to locate this one
#include <QMessageBox>              // Not able to locate this one
#include "Sum_Shader.h"
#include "ui_WavefrontRenderer.h"   // Not able to locate this one
#include "Container.h"
#include "sph.h"
#include "ResourceManager.h"
#include "Camera.h"
#include "Font.h"
#include <Camera.h>
```

The missing files are in the root location of the project

C:\Users\User1\source\repos\MyProject

when i move the Project to another system in the following location

C:\Users\User2\source\repos\MyProject

The header in root project are shown as missing.

[image]

Comment: You should adapt your project to use project-relative header paths instead of absolute paths.

Comment: Define: "location" - do you mean a different local filesystem location? A different computer? A different operating system and compiler toolchain entirely?

Comment: @Dai a different system

Comment: I'm afraid Botje's comment is actually the answer here.

Comment: https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/cpp/gcc_make.html#zz-1.8 

You need to set -L -I options as needed for libraries and include files outside your own source. Path to you own headers should be relative paths.

Comment: The `ui_WaveFrontRenderer.h` should be auto-generated by Qt's `uic` tool, the Qt headers should come from a Qt installation on the second system.

Comment: @Botje i have installed QT at the same location as previous system , would that be enough.

Comment: It's your project definition, I have no way of knowing that. Perhaps your project definition relies on environment variables to find Qt? Typically that is called `QTDIR` but please go look at the include / linker paths to see what it wants instead of guessing!

Comment: @shomit are you using QT Creator? if so, please post your .pro file and the exact errors you have.

Comment: @Botje  these are my include paths for QT.

Comment: Sometimes VS gets a bit confused over relative directories! Try changing your `.\GeneratedFiles` to `$(ProjectDir)GeneratedFiles` and `.\GeneratedFiles\Release` to `$(ProjectDir)GeneratedFiles\Release`.

Comment: #include "" is different from #include <>, #include ""  these files may be the .h file which you write. #include <> these files is in the Include Path, and these files can also be included by #include "". So when you move from one location to other(On one PC), #include <> has no error, but  #include "" will report error if the .h file is not in root directory of the project. Because the VS cannot find the files. And When you move from one location to other(two different PCs) ,#include <> and #include "" will report error because VS cannot find .h files in the Include Path.